# Limit by different field than order in MySQL statement?

Tags: mysql

Okay, lets say I have the following MySQL query:

```
SELECT table1.*, COUNT(table2.link_id) AS count
FROM table1
    LEFT JOIN table2 on (table1.key = table2.link_id)
GROUP BY table1.key
ORDER BY table1.name ASC
LIMIT 20
```

Simple right? It returns the `table1` info, with the number of times each row is linked in `table2`.

However, you'll notice that it limits the resulting rows to 20... and sorts the resulting rows by `table1.name`. What this does is return the top 20 results in alphabetical order.

What I was wondering if there was a way I could limit to the top 20 results based on `count` in descending order; while ALSO getting the remaining 20 results in alphabetical order. I know I can simply sort the returned array in a followup code, but I'm wondering if there is a way to do this in a single query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use subselect for limit, and sort in the outer select

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT table1.*, COUNT(table2.link_id) AS count
FROM table1
    LEFT JOIN table2 on (table1.key = table2.link_id)
GROUP BY table1.key
ORDER BY count DESC
LIMIT 20 ) t
ORDER BY name ASC
```